# How to rewrite url with double directory names using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm having a hard time rewriting the following url:

http://example-url.com/example-url.com/anythinggoeshere

to:

http://example-url.com/anythinggoeshere

I tried this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 example-url.com/example-url.com(.*) example-url.com$1
```

But it's not doing anything...

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I tried this for example:

RedirectMatch 301 http://example-url.com/example-url.com(.*) http://example-url.com$1

Comment: There are double dots in the url ..typo?

Comment: yes typo, i changed it, no typo in the real htaccess though...

Comment: Post this code to your question and not here in the comment area.

Comment: Is the /example-url.com a web directory?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by doing the following:

```
Redirect 301 /example-url.com http://example-url.com
```